# How can I superimpose two images in XML?

Tags: xml, xamarin.forms

I would like insert an image with octagonal shape. So i thought to superimpose the octagonal shape (with trasparent background) to image. How is it possible?

I have the image in a simple grid but I don't know how to superimpose the octagonal shape on it

I have this xml code:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="LogoConRegalo.png"/>
        <Image x:Name="ProfilePicture" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="Profile.png" TranslationY="50" VerticalOptions="End"/>
```

With the solution proposed:
[image]

Comment: just place both images the same grid cell

Comment: @Jason i have this xml code, how can I put the two images in the same cell?

Answer (score 0):

just place both images the same grid cell

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ... />
<Image x:Name="Image2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ... />
```

Comment: What are they doing?  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: in your XAML one image has HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions and Translation properties assigned and the other one does not.  That could cause them to be laid out in different areas of the same cell instead of on top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

According your description , try this code snippet help you:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0">     
      <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="LogoConRegalo.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
   </StackLayout>
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10"> 
      <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="Profile.png" Aspect="AspectFit" Padding="5" />
   </StackLayout> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the result like following screenshot?

[image]

Here are two image from your layout.

**sharp.jpg**

[image]

**image.jpg**

[image]

Here is code

```
<StackLayout>
        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0">
                <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="sharp.jpg" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="10">
                <Image HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="image.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit"  />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```